# SLIM Separating out route from function using TWIG

Tags: php, twig, slim

If I want to separate out the route from the function what is the best way as I still need to `use($app,$twig)`

```
$app->get('/app(/:date(/:time))', function ($date = null,$time = null) use ($app,$twig)     {       
    //do some stuff using TWIG
}); 
 $app->run();
```

new route, function  `function app(...`

```
$app->get('/app(/:date(/:time))', 'app');
```

Edit 1 - Next try using a class give a `Undefined variable: twig'

```
$actions = new Actions($app, $twig);

$app->get('/app(/:date(/:time))', [$actions, 'app']);   
$app->run();


class Actions {

    protected $app, $twig;

    public function __construct($app, $twig) {
        $this->app  = $app;
        $this->twig = $twig;
    }

    public function app($date = null,$time = null) {
        // print_r($:date);

    //  get some data using date time

        $template = $twig->loadTemplate('template.php');
            echo $template->render(array(
            ........
            ));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$appFunc = function () use ($app, $twig) ...
$app->get(..., $appFunc);
```

or:

```
class Actions {

    protected $app, $twig;

    public function __construct($app, $twig) {
        $this->app  = $app;
        $this->twig = $twig;
    }

    public function app() ...

}

$actions = new Actions($app, $twig);

$app->get(..., [$actions, 'app']);
```

or:

```
function app($app, $twig) {
    return function () use ($app, $twig) ...
}

$app->get(..., app($app, $twig));
```

<sub>Or *cough*`global`*cough*.</sub>

Comment: I hope you get that cough sorted soon Deceze

Comment: Thanks Deceze,above gives me a `Undefined variable: twig`